# How can i get a response from the server to a client message

Tags: java, sockets, networking, server, client

I am wondering how i would be able to send a message from the server back to the client. I'm new to Java and have searched up the problem however the code used is unfamiliar to what i've been learning with. I've tried to do it however i cannnot quite get it to send the message back to the client.

I want to sent the message "message revieved" from the server to the client once the client sends the message  "first" to the server.

Any help with explanation would be really appreciated!

**Client Code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {

//Main Method:- called when running the class file.
public static void main(String[] args){ 

    //Portnumber:- number of the port we wish to connect on.
    int portNumber = 15882;
    //ServerIP:- IP address of the server.
    String serverIP = "localhost";

    try{
        //Create a new socket for communication
        Socket soc = new Socket(serverIP,portNumber);

        // create new instance of the client writer thread, intialise it and 
start it running
        ClientWriter clientWrite = new ClientWriter(soc);
        Thread clientWriteThread = new Thread(clientWrite);
        clientWriteThread.start();

    }
    catch (Exception except){
        //Exception thrown (except) when something went wrong, pushing 
message to the console
        System.out.println("Error --> " + except.getMessage());
    }
  }
}

//This thread is responcible for writing messages
 class ClientWriter implements Runnable
 {
 Socket cwSocket = null;

 public ClientWriter (Socket outputSoc){
    cwSocket = outputSoc;
 }   
 public void run(){
    try{
        //Create the outputstream to send data through
        DataOutputStream dataOut = new 
DataOutputStream(cwSocket.getOutputStream());

        System.out.println("Client writer running");

        //Write message to output stream and send through socket
        dataOut.writeUTF("First");     // writes to output stream
        dataOut.flush();                       // sends through socket 

        //close the stream once we are done with it
        dataOut.close();
    }
    catch (Exception except){
        //Exception thrown (except) when something went wrong, pushing 
message to the console
        System.out.println("Error in Writer--> " + except.getMessage());
    }
 }
}

class ClientListener implements Runnable
{
Socket clSocket = null;

public ClientListener (Socket inputSoc) {
    clSocket = inputSoc;
}

public void run() {
    try {

        // need to write here to recieve message 
        DataInputStream dataIn = new 
DataInputStream(clSocket.getInputStream());           // new stuff
        String msg = dataIn.readUTF();
        System.out.print(msg);

    }
    catch (Exception except){
        //Exception thrown (except) when something went wrong, pushing 
message to the console
        System.out.println("Error in Writer--> " + except.getMessage());
    }
  }


}
```

**Server Code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Serv {

//Main Method:- called when running the class file.
public static void main(String[] args){ 

    //Portnumber:- number of the port we wish to connect on.
    int portNumber = 15882;
    try{
        //Setup the socket for communication 
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ServerSocket serverSoc = new ServerSocket(portNumber);

        while (true){

            //accept incoming communication
            System.out.println("Waiting for client");
            Socket soc = serverSoc.accept();

            DataOutputStream dos = new 
DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeUTF("Message Recieved");                                                
// new stuff
            dos.flush();                         //need to flush

            //create a new thread for the connection and start it.
            ServerConnetionHandler sch = new ServerConnetionHandler(soc);
            Thread schThread = new Thread(sch);
            schThread.start();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception except){
        //Exception thrown (except) when something went wrong, pushing 
message to the console
        System.out.println("Error --> " + except.getMessage());
    }
  }   
}

class ServerConnetionHandler implements Runnable
{
Socket clientSocket = null;

public ServerConnetionHandler (Socket inSoc){
    clientSocket = inSoc;
}

public void run(){
    try{
        //Catch the incoming data in a data stream, read a line and output 
it to the console
        DataInputStream dataIn = new 
DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

        System.out.println("Client Connected");
        //Print out message
        System.out.println("--> " + dataIn.readUTF());

        //close the stream once we are done with it
        dataIn.close();
    }
    catch (Exception except){
        //Exception thrown (except) when something went wrong, pushing 
message to the console
        System.out.println("Error in ServerHandler--> " + 
except.getMessage());
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problems and fixed them in both classes for you, but before I give you the code, let's talk about why yours didn't exactly work.

In the `client` code, you set up the stream correctly, and connected to the server, but right after you were trying to send a message to the server, there was this piece of code:

```
//close the stream once we are done with it
dataOut.close();
```

DO NOT close your `outputstream` if you are going to be waiting for a response later on, if this were a direct one-way message, (Client->Server), and nothing more, this would be okay. Because you had this, in simple terms, it closes the socket communication between the `server` and `client`.

After that, I noticed you had another class called `ClientListener`, but silly thing is, it wasn't ever called! So it would cause an error on the server side when it was trying to send a reply back, as obviously, the client wasn't listening for anything. So I fixed it and added this code in the `try` statement in the `ClientWriter` class.

```
ClientListener listener = new ClientListener(cwSocket);
new Thread(listener).start();
```

Now we can move on to the `serv` class and see what was going on there.
One big problem I noticed right away was that once the server was initialized and waiting for a `client` to connect, It sent a response back to the client without reading anything it had to say! It's always best to read what the client has sent you before sending any data back, or it can cause errors.
But alas, you had a `ServerConnectionHandler` class to listen for incoming data, but that was called after you sent a reply back to the `client`. It should have been listening before even a reply was sent, not only to prevent errors, but also so you can listen for data, because you aren't able to listen for data after an output stream has written something (Unless server is constructed in a different way.) 
I shortened the `serv` class by a lot, but overall, great job for being a beginner! Here are the modified and working classes below:

**Client**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {


public static void main(String[] args){ 

//Portnumber:- number of the port we wish to connect on.
int portNumber = 15882;

//ServerIP:- IP address of the server.
String serverIP = "localhost";

try{
    //Create a new socket for communication
    Socket soc = new Socket(serverIP, portNumber);

    // create new instance of the client writer thread, intialise it and start it running
    ClientWriter clientWrite = new ClientWriter(soc);
    new Thread(clientWrite).start();
    //Shortened code a bit.

    //Thread clientWriteThread = new Thread(clientWrite);
    //clientWriteThread.start();





}
catch (Exception except){
    //Exception thrown (except) when something went wrong, pushing message to the console
    System.out.println("Error --> " + except.getMessage());
}
}}






//This thread is responcible for writing messages
class ClientWriter implements Runnable
 {

 Socket cwSocket = null;

 public ClientWriter (Socket outputSoc){
cwSocket = outputSoc;
 }   


public void run(){
try{
    //Create the outputstream to send data through
    DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(cwSocket.getOutputStream());

    System.out.println("Client writer running");

    //Write message to output stream and send through socket
    dataOut.writeUTF("First");     // writes to output stream
    dataOut.flush();               // sends through socket 

    //close the stream once we are done with it
    //dataOut.close();
        //Closing the stream will close the connection between the server and client.
        //DO NOT close an input stream or output stream when communicating with
        //each other, unless it is one way communication...


   //Where is the listener? It's never called, so we can't listen for anything!
   ClientListener listener = new ClientListener(cwSocket);
   new Thread(listener).start();

}
catch (Exception except){
    //Exception thrown (except) when something went wrong, pushing message to the console
    System.out.println("Error in Writer--> " + except.getMessage());
    except.printStackTrace();
}
 }
}




class ClientListener implements Runnable
{
Socket clSocket = null;

public ClientListener (Socket inputSoc) {
clSocket = inputSoc;
}

public void run() {
try {

    // need to write here to recieve message 
    DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(clSocket.getInputStream());           // new stuff
    String msg = dataIn.readUTF();
    System.out.print(msg);



}
catch (Exception except){
    //Exception thrown (except) when something went wrong, pushing message to the console
    System.out.println("Error in Writer--> " + except.getMessage());
    except.printStackTrace();
}
  }


}
```

**Server**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Serv {

//Main Method:- called when running the class file.
public static void main(String[] args){ 

//Portnumber:- number of the port we wish to connect on.
int portNumber = 15882;
try{
    //Setup the socket for communication 
    ServerSocket serverSoc = new ServerSocket(portNumber);

    while (true){
        //accept incoming communication
        System.out.println("Waiting for client");
        Socket soc = serverSoc.accept();

        /* It's best to initialize both the input and output streams at the same time
         * Make sure you read what the other stream said before writing to it,
         * or it can be a cluttered error causing mess.
        */

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());



        //Read what client sent us
        System.out.println("Message Received: -->" + dataIn.readUTF());

        //Send reply back to client
        dos.writeUTF("Message Recieved");    // new stuff
        dos.flush();                         //need to flush


        //Close the inputstream and output stream so we can disconnect this user
        //and wait for another one to connect.
        dataIn.close();
        dos.close();


        //Can not read after writing back, doesn't make sense

        //create a new thread for the connection and start it.
        //ServerConnetionHandler sch = new ServerConnetionHandler(soc);
        //Thread schThread = new Thread(sch);
        //schThread.start();
    }
}
catch (Exception except){
    //Exception thrown (except) when something went wrong, pushing message to the console
    System.out.println("Error --> " + except.getMessage());
    except.printStackTrace();
}
}}



/*The last code you had was all wrong. Up in the server, you were
 * writing a reply back to the client and then waiting for a response...
 * You can't listen for something after you wrote back (failed to write back
 * anyway due to some problems)
 * You can remove this code below, as it is redundant.
 */
/*
class ServerConnetionHandler implements Runnable
{
Socket clientSocket = null;

public ServerConnetionHandler (Socket inSoc){
clientSocket = inSoc;
}

public void run(){
try{
    //Catch the incoming data in a data stream, read a line and output it to the console
    DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

    System.out.println("Client Connected");
    //Print out message
    System.out.println("--> " + dataIn.readUTF());

    //close the stream once we are done with it
    dataIn.close();
}
catch (Exception except){
    //Exception thrown (except) when something went wrong, pushing message to the console
    System.out.println("Error in ServerHandler--> " + 
            except.getMessage());
}
   }*/
```

Comment: Wow thank u so much! i couldn't have asked for a better answer and explanation. Really appreciate that!